# Not able to access click event with jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am having a hard time accessing a click even with my jQuery selector. Here is my HTML:

```
<li class="handle-bars">
    <span class="fa fa-bars pull-right text-primary m-t-10"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-cogs pull-right text-primary m-t-10" id="trigger-modal-editor" style="cursor:pointer" data-target="#modalSlideLeft" data-toggle="modal">     </span>
</li>
```

Here is my jQuery selector:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#trigger-modal-editor').click(function() {
    alert('Hello');
  });
</script>
```

This is not registering the art for some reason. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That *should* work. You forgot to close `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` though. If the elements are dynamically generated, use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting to close the ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#trigger-modal-editor').click(function() {
    alert('Hello');
  });
});//this
```

Also, you don't have any text inside `#trigger-modal-editor`, place some text there to click in.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the closing brace and parenthesis to the post, but they are in my actual code. The span is creating a font awesome icon and I am wanting to trigger the click even when the icon is clicked. The class responsible for this is fa fa-cogs. Any other suggestions?

Comment: try $(document).on('click', '#trigger-modal-editor',function() {

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you very much! Is there a reason this worked and my code did not?